# WIndowsServer2019でRDS環境を作成しているが、RDSのドメイン外PCから接続できない。

Tags: windows, rds

＜前提＞
・RDSライセンスサーバはADサーバに構築済み。
・RDSブローカーサーバは仮想サーバ
・RDSセッションサーバは4台
・PINGやIPアドレスでのリモートデスクトップ接続は可能。

＜現象＞
内系サーバにRDS環境を構築し、外系に所属しているクライアントからリモート接続できるように
したのですが、「リモートコンピュータが見つかりませんでした。」と表示されて接続
することが出来ません。

＜構成＞
【内系】
ドメイン名(DNS)：ad1.local
ドメインコントローラ名：win2019/FQDNはadsv01.ad1.local
ドメインコントローラIPアドレス：192.168.10.10/24

RDSブローカーサーバ名：rdssv1
RDSブローカーサーバIPアドレス：192.168.10.11/24

【外系】
ドメイン名(DNS)：ad2.local
ドメインコントローラー名：win2019/FQDNはadsv11.ad2.local
ドメインコントローラーのIPアドレス：192.168.20.20/24

【クライアント】
外系のドメインに参加している。

【原因（仮定）】
・名前解決ができていない。
→これはDNSで名前解決する必要がありますでしょうか？
・そもそもどっかの設定間違え
→気になる設定はありますでしょうか？

結構はまってしまっております。
皆様のお知恵を拝借させてくださいませ。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: クライアントから「rdssv1.ad1.local」の名前解決が出来て、pingは通るのでしょうか。

Comment: 念のため確認ですが、ここでの「RDS」はMicrosoftの「リモートデスクトップサービス」を指していますか？ ("Amazon RDS" というのもあるようなので)

Comment: 回答される方へ　https://okwave.jp/qa/q9714849.html

Comment: @htb 様　pingはIPアドレスでは通りますが、FQDNでは通らないですね。

Comment: @cubick♦ 様 Windwsのリモートデスクトップサービスになります。

Comment: 皆様解決いたしました。
詳細な原因は不明ですが、どうやらネットワークの設定がおかしかったみたいです。
ありがとうございました！